# Python socket recv doesn't give good result

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, networking

I am trying to build a program for my IT course. The point of the program is to have a client app to send commands to the server. It seemd to work pretty well until today where, after a few calls, when I receive a response from the server it is not up to date.

eg : I send a few commands that all work fine. But then send another command and receive the response from the previous one.

I checked the command sent by the client and it is the one I type and in the server part, when I receive a command from the client it is the one actually sent by the client (not the previous one)

Here is the Shell classes (in the server and client) that I use to send and receive messages aswell as an example on how I use it.

Server :

```
class Shell:
command = ""
next_command = True

def __init__(self, malware_os):
    self._os = malware_os
    self._response = ""

def receive(self):
    self.command = distant_socket.recv(4096).decode("utf-8")

def execute_command(self):
    if self.command[:2] == "cd":
        os.chdir(self.command[3:])
        if self._os == "Windows":
            self.result = Popen("cd", shell=True, stdout=PIPE)
        else:
            self.result = Popen("pwd", shell=True, stdout=PIPE)
    else:
        self.result = Popen(self.command, shell=True, stdout=PIPE)

    self._response = self.result.communicate()

def send(self):
    self._response = self._response[0]
    self._response = self._response.decode("utf-8", errors="ignore")
    self._response = self._response + " "
    self._response = self._response.encode("utf-8")
    distant_socket.send(self._response)
    self._response = None
```

Use in server :

```
    shell.receive()
    shell.execute_command()
    shell.send()
```

Client :

```
class Shell:

    def __init__(self):
        self._history = []
        self._command = ""

    def send(self):
        self._history.append(self._command)
        s.send(self._command.encode("utf-8"))

    def receive(self):
        content = s.recv(4096).decode("utf-8", errors="ignore")
        if content[2:] == "cd":
            malware_os.chdir(self._command[3:].decode("utf-8", errors="ignore"))
        print(content)

    def history(self):
        print("The history of your commands is:")
        print("----------------------")
        for element in self._history:
            print(element)

    def get_command(self):
        return self._command

    def set_command(self, command):
        self._command = command
```

Use in client :

```
shell.set_command(getinfo.get_users())
shell.send()
shell.receive()
```

Thank you in advance for your help,
Cordially,
Sasquatch

Comment: You don't have a proper receive loop, and it doesn't look like you have a protocol that can work. I will look for a dup for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you said the response is not up to date, I'm guessing you used TCP (you didn't post the socket creation). Like the comment mentioned, there are 2 things that you aren't doing right:

1. Protocol: TCP gives you a stream, which is divided as the OS sees fit into packets. When transferring data over the network, the receiving end must know when it has a complete transmission. The easiest way to do that would be to send the length of the transmission, in a fixed format (say 4 bytes, big endian), before the transmission itself. Also, use sendall. For example:

```py
import struct
def send_message(sock, message_str):
    message_bytes = message_str.encode("utf-8")
    size_prefix = struct.pack("!I", len(message_bytes)) # I means 4 bytes integer in big endian
    sock.sendall(size_prefix)
    sock.sendall(message_bytes)
```

2. Since TCP is a stream socket, the receiving end might return from recv before the entire message was received. You need to call it in a loop, checking the return value at every iteration to correctly handle disconnects. Something such as:

```py
def recv_message_str(sock):
    #first, get the message size, assuming you used the send above
    size_buffer = b""
    while len(size_buffer) != 4:
        recv_ret = sock.recv(4 - len(size_buffer))
        if len(recv_ret) == 0:
            # The other side disconnected, do something (raise an exception or something)
            raise Exception("socket disconnected")
        size_buffer += recv_ret
    size = struct.unpack("!I", size_buffer)[0]
    
    # Loop again, for the message string
    message_buffer = b""
    while len(message_buffer) != size:
        recv_ret = sock.recv(size - len(message_buffer))
        if len(recv_ret) == 0:
            # The other side disconnected, do something (raise an exception or something)
            raise Exception("socket disconnected")
        message_buffer += recv_ret
    return message_buffer.decode("utf-8", errors="ignore")
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Tomer! This actually saved me.